# Error while running shell script command rom python

Tags: python

```
cmd = "sed -i '$ a {0}' {1}".format(string, file_path)
os.system(cmd)
```

My string is some tab separated.But when i am running my python prog i am getting

```
sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
```

I had seen command going in os.system and it is :

```
sed -i '$ a A   B   "Talco Powder"' file
```

Comment: How are you executing your python script?

Comment: what does file_path and string equal to?

Answer (score 0):

Using quoted strings in Python is tricky, you can use `shlex` and `subprocess` to help you run such commands:

```
import shlex
import subprocess

cmd = "sed -i '$ a {0}' {1}".format(string, file_path)
subprocess.run(shlex.split(cmd))
```

Comment: what in case  if i give 30/01/2020 in single quotes which is completely enclosed in double quotes ? then also i am getting same error

Comment: i don't understand the question, can you paste the full input you are trying to use and the error you are getting? you can add it to the original question i think